# is it possible to use a firewall to view list of accessed websites?

Tags: firewall

all i want is the list of websites that are accessed. i run a small enterprise and have the authority to install software since am the admin. please note that the requirement is not to block access to specific sites etc. its to kind of spy on a particular candidate(he's been acting suspiciously for some time).

i could simply view the browser history but it can be cleared very easily. so i want a log of websites visited. is there any firewall that records this data?

Comment: Please be careful with this one, as some countries protect certain classes of employees from being tracked without being told beforehand... meaning you could violate their rights in your country/area. Please check with a lawyer first. And finally, it may be possible with a firewall, but you'll need a proxy instead

Comment: Also, can you edit your question for basic capitalization and grammar? It will help future visitors as well

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to do this with a "standard" firewall (but may be technically possible). As @Abraxas said, it is better to use a proxy service (and indeed that is what advanced firewalls do)

If its just a one off there may be easier ways of doing this - including (if you own the device) using keystroke logging software - which has other advantages including the ability to see SSL URLs.

Another way may be to simply log traffic from his computer to your DNS server (if you run your own DNS server).  This won't tell you the pages he is going to, but will give you a good idea of the websites (ie won't tell you if he is going to "http://abc.de.ef/hello" or "http://abc.de.ef/im_a_bad_person" but it will tell you he is going to abc.de.ef

Comment: thanks david, but i want to know the specific urls that the guy is visiting.....the solution i have found is to use squid proxy server so that any internet traffic will first have to go through it

Comment: track4win is another solution

Comment: but squid is for linux. the windows version is no longer being maintained. so if anyone knows any windows equivalent of squid, please chip in

Comment: Squid is maintained and available for Windows - http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BinaryPackages#Windows.  A simple google search also reveals a number of proxy servers for windows.  The difficulty you may have is intercepting the traffic unless you can reconfigure the system to manually use a proxy server or use a pac file.

Comment: the windows link u posted points to the cygwin implementation of squid..am not familiar with cygwin....maybe its kind of like a virtual machine to run linux apps in windows

Comment: Cygwin is not a VM.  The way I understand it its software which provides a "Linux Type" environment under Windows.

Comment: ok i'll give it a shot....